# Nuxt3 & Nuxt I18n Plugin doesn't detect Browser language preference & Deployement issue

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt-i18n

Actually working with Nuxt3 RC [Documentation](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/) and it's dedicated plugin Nuxt/I18n [Documentation](https://v8.i18n.nuxtjs.org)

I encountered two issues:

First issue is that I'm failing to detect Browser preference language it always fallback on the default local and I saw that the cookie wasn't set until I change the language with `useSwitchLocalePath()`
note: Switching language works, I've got the /en and the cookie

My second issue is when I'm generating my static site with `nuxi generate` and once the website is deployed, going to my root path '/' sends back a 404 but my localhost handles the path and redirect to .../en for example, maybe the issue is from the prefix strategie that I used because of what I've read in the documentation under

```
This strategy combines both previous strategies behaviors, meaning that you will get URLs with prefixes for every language, but URLs for the default language will also have a non-prefixed version (though the prefixed version will be preferred when detectBrowserLanguage is enabled.
```

This was my `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [
     '@nuxtjs/i18n'
  ],
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: "en",
    baseUrl: 'https://*****',    
    strategy: "prefix",
    detectBrowserLanguage: {      
      useCookie: true,      
      cookieKey: 'i18n_lang',      
      redirectOn: 'root',  
    },
    locales: [
      { code: 'en', iso: "en-US", name: "ENGLISH", file: 'en-US.json', isCatchallLocale: true }, 
      { code: 'fr', iso: "fr-FR", name: "FRENCH", file: 'fr-FR.json' }],
    lazy: true, 
    langDir: 'locales'
  }
})
```

To try it out I configured my Chrome to be in French and my Firefox to be in English
To set the language using the browser pref I've added a file in my pluging folder launch.client.js

```js
import { getCookie } from "../utils/cookie"

const LANG_COOKIE_NAME = "i18n_lang"
const LANG_COOKIE_DATE = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365).toGMTString()
const LANG_COOKIE_SAME_SITE = "Lax"

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  if (getCookie(LANG_COOKIE_NAME) !== undefined) return

  let browserLangPref = navigator.language
  const { locales, setLocale } = nuxtApp.$i18n
  const availableLocales = [...locales.value.map(el => el.code), ...locales.value.map(el => el.iso)]

  if (!availableLocales.includes(browserLangPref)) browserLangPref = "en"

  document.cookie = `${LANG_COOKIE_NAME}=${browserLangPref}; expires=${LANG_COOKIE_DATE}; path=/; SameSite=${LANG_COOKIE_SAME_SITE}`;
  setLocale(browserLangPref)
})
```

This workaround works but doesn't seem to be a clean way of doing this

For the deployment issue I switch back to the prefix_and_default strategie and with my plugins everything seem ok

I'm just asking myself if this wasn't a good way to go, maybe I just didn't understood something in the documentation

Maybe somebody has a functionnal repo with this use case and that I can check.

Answer (score 0):

If you use server side rendering than I would use something like this:

```
if (process.server) {
      const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp()
      const reqLocale = nuxtApp.ssrContext?.event.node.req.headers['accept-language']?.split(',')[0]
      if (reqLocale) {
        return reqLocale
      }
    }
```